How to Configure Solana Wallet Adapter with Next.js Middleware for Subdomain Redirects?
I'm building a decentralized application (dApp) using Next.js and Solana, and I need some help with integrating the Solana Wallet Adapter in a way that works with subdomain redirects handled by Next.js middleware.
Context:

Framework: Next.js
Hosting: Vercel
Blockchain: Solana
Wallet Integration: Solana Wallet Adapter
Requirement: Users can access specific subdirectories of my site through custom subdomains (e.g., subdomain.mysite.com should serve content from mysite.com/subdirectory).

What I've Done So Far:

Custom Domains and Subdomains: Configured on Vercel and DNS settings.
Next.js Middleware for Subdomain Redirects:

Created _middleware.js to rewrite requests from subdomains to specific subdirectories.


Basic Solana Wallet Integration:

Installed @solana/wallet-adapter and @solana/wallet-adapter-react.



Code Example:
_middleware.js for handling subdomain redirects:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req) {
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
  const subdomain = url.hostname.split('.')[0];

  if (subdomain && subdomain !== 'www' && subdomain !== 'mysite') {
    url.pathname = `/${subdomain}${url.pathname}`;
    return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

Basic setup for Solana Wallet Adapter:
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletModalProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { PhantomWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';

const wallets = [new PhantomWalletAdapter()];

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint="https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com">
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
        <WalletModalProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;

Issues I'm Facing:

When the subdomain redirect occurs via middleware, the Solana Wallet Adapter loses its state, causing wallet disconnection and Wallet not ready state error.
Wallet connection state doesn't persist across subdomain redirects.

What I Need:

Guidance on how to configure the Solana Wallet Adapter to maintain wallet connection state across subdomain redirects managed by Next.js middleware.
Any best practices or examples of handling similar scenarios in a Next.js dApp with subdomain routing.

Additional Information:

Next.js version: 14.x
Solana Wallet Adapter version: latest
Vercel for hosting

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!
